# PyQt setGeometry sets client size; how to set size of entire window?

Tags: qt, pyqt

```
class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
```

When this window opens, the client area of the window will cover exactly (x, y, w, h).

But the overall window, with borders, title, and menubar, covers a larger area.

I want my initial overall window to exactly cover (x, y, w, h), without regard to client area size.  How do I do it?

Comment: I don't think it can be done as the window frame is OS/window manager dependent. See: https://forum.qt.io/topic/9496/setting-window-size-including-window-frame

Comment: @three_pineapples: looks like you are right.  That's enough to convince me to hardcode the offsets for my particular platform.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably you should read [Window Geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) in the Qt Docs. At first glance, it looks like `frameGeometry` might help, but that is only useful once the window is already shown. So really, the best compromise is to allow the user to resize the window as appropriate, save the geometry on close, and then restore on open.